# Get console output an screenshot attached to allure report- selenium webdriver, testng, maven

Tags: maven, selenium, allure

I am using allure reporting. My report is generated correctly, but i screenshots and console output is not attached to report.

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-BETA14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please find screenshot attached of [image: allure report]
It shows status pass/fail/broken and time taken to run test. But console output is not attached to it. Also screenshots for failed test cases are stored in folder surefire-reports/screenshots. I need to attach them too to allure reports.Can someone please help in knowing what i need to add to get this output?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you aren't going to be adding enough details to your question in terms of what you have done (you would need to share code snippets which can perhaps be executed by others to simulate the problem that you are experiencing), where you are stuck with and what help you are expecting, there's a very high chance that your question is going to be closed off. Please help enrich your question with contextual details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are getting the failure screenshot using TestNG listener and you have access to the testNG listener. Else see how to create a TestNG listener (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml) by overriding the TestListenerAdapter.

1. It seems you can create a method like the following for saving screenshot

   ```
   @Attachment(value = "Page screenshot", type = "image/png")
   public byte[] saveScreenshot() {
       // Use selenium screenshot code to take screenshot and convert into     byte[]
       return byte[];
   }
   ```

   You can then call this method in your testNG listener used to take screenshot on test failure.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onTestFailure(ITestResult testResult) {
       saveScreenshot();
       super.onTestFailure(testResult);
   }
   ```
2. For getting the console output to report, create the following method

   ```
   @Attachment
   public String logOutput(List<String> outputList) {
       String output = ""; 
       for (String o : outputList) 
           output += o + "<br/>"; 
       return output
   }
   ```

   Call the method onTest(success, failure, skip) and onConfiguration (success, failure, skip) in the testNG listener

   ```
   @Override
   public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult testResult) {
       // Reporter.getOutput(testResult)will give the output logged in testng reporter
       logOutput(Reporter.getOutput(testResult));
       super.onTestSuccess(testResult);
   }
   ```

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki/Attachments